# Need Cryptography Libraries in .NET CF 1.0

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, compact-framework, aes

My company has begun to work with a vendor which is requiring us to write our integration code based on the .NET Compact Framework 1.0. For numerous business reasons, we need to encrypt data in this process. While we could write a custom XTEA algorithm, we would like to implement some type of AES encryption due to the sensitivity of the data.

I know that by default .NET Compact Framework 1.0 does not have the System.Security namespace. Is there any way to back port/add the .NET Framework 1.1 System.Security namespace and its requirements to .NET CF 1.0?

If not, are there any existing projects/methodologies for implementing AES encryption on .NET CF 1.0?

Comment: really .NET CF 1.0 in 2013?, Anyway I think `BouncyCastle` supports CF1.0 http://www.bouncycastle.org/index.html

Comment: Yeah... we about fell out of our chairs when they said they required less than 3.0 (before we knew the full details) - but thanks I will look into Bouncy Castle.

Comment: Note that you can always copy source code from Bouncy, there is no need to use the entire library, as long as you keep the license information intact. Also note that it is strongly advisable not to use a library or - in your case - an entire runtime that does not receive security updates for security relevant applications.

Comment: Writing a custom XTEA algorithm is of course a very bad idea. If you need a fast stream cipher, use salsa20 or something similar up to date cipher that has been tested well.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @owlstead - and yes we aren't fond about the XTEA idea, that is just how the vendor currently implements all of their "security".

Comment: @sa_ddam213 it looks like BouncyCastle will work - I have a working AES encrypt/decrypt class - now it's just a matter of throwing together a decrepit emulation environment that only has .NET CF 1.0 installed so that I can verify functionality.  Can you add your solution as an answer so that I can give you credit.

Comment: @Eli, Glad yu got it sorted,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `BouncyCastle` supports CF1.0 for AES encryption/decryption

Link:
bouncycastle.org/index.html

Good luck with the project as it sounds like it going to be painful working with CF1.0
(OMG no `Linq`, ROFL)

Comment: Finally got it working.... at least encryption anyway. You think no Linq is bad - try no method overloads. BouncyCastle didn't work at all until I wrote in handlers for basic things like converting between types and getting the length of objects/arrays, etc... this is going to be a nightmare. But seriously, thanks a ton.